# Microsoft Azure WebApp Deployment Plan

Tags: azure

Need help on below points:

1. Data out limit for free tier is 165 MB. How is data out usage calculated?
2. I am using a free tier subscription type. Why does Memory usage increase as soon as memory resets after 1 hour? Why does my application take 230-240 MB of memory initially?
3. I have a free tier account with credit amount xxx Rs. Can I use the free tier amount for another subscription like basic or standard?
4. Are there any data out and memory usage limit for other subscriptions like basic/Premium/standard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Outgoing traffic
2. Its the memory taken by the IIS instance, thats expected in Azure
3. I don't understand, but you can use money from your subscription and you cannot use Tiers together, so pay for a free tier, but get all the benefits of a Premium Tier.
4. You can take a look at the limits on the [pricing page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/).

Comment: can i upgrade free tier memory usage from 165 MB to 1GB etc.?

Comment: Regarding point no. 3,  I have free tier account with credit amount 6000 Rs. Can I use free tier amount for the other subscription like basic or standard? e.g. I am having credit amount as 6000 Rs. for free tier. Now in the free tier there are limitations in terms of Memory, Data out. Now suppose I want to take new subscription (Basic/Standard) then in these new subscription can I use/adjust free tier amount ?

Comment: no, you can't, you need to change the tier to get better performance, that was aimed at @HarshalY. For VikramGharge: you are confusing Azure Subscription with App Service Plan, you can use Azure Credits for any resources that you like, it doesn't matter, you can create 1,2,3,10,50, so on App Service Plans in the same subscription and they can all differ, some can be free, some shared, some basic, etc